# quick way to fit the same mixed model to multiple dataframes or subsets in R?

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have dataset containing growth data for multiple crops. The experiment treatment is within-crop (i.e. I am not comparing between crops) and has a randomised block design, with repeated measures over time. I would like to run the same mixed model on each different crop in R:

`model<-lmer(response~treatment*time+(1|block), data=data)`

My dataset contains 20 crops and I want to extract all the fixed intercepts and coefficients, so it is annoying to run the model on each crop separately. Somehow I got the impression from some other posts that lmList, given the below formula, would run a separate but common mixed model on each crop. However having now checked the help page and the output in more detail, I think it just does a fixed effect linear model (lm).

`model_set <- lme4::lmList(response~treatment*time+(1|block)|crop,data=data)`

I can't find any nice posts on setting up a loop to run the same mixed effect model on multiple datasets and extract coefficients, or if there is any existing function for this. It would be great if someone could recommend a quick simple solution.

As an example dataset I suggest the lme4 sleepstudy data, but let's just make a fake 'group' factor to mimic my 'crop' factor:

```
library(lme4)
data(sleepstudy)
library(car)
sleepstudy$group<-recode(sleepstudy$Subject,
  " c('308','309','310','330','331','332','333','334') = 'group1'; 
    c('335','337','349','350','351','352','369','370','371','372') = 'group2'")
model<-lmer(Reaction~Days+(1|Subject), data=sleepstudy)
```

How can I automate running the same model on each group separately and then extracting the intercept and coefficients?

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I have stumbled across the 'split' function, which means I can answer my own question. The split function subsets a dataframe into a list of dataframes based on levels of a specified factor. A simple loop can then be set up to run the same model on each dataframe in the list.

```
list_df <- split(sleepstudy, sleepstudy$group) #split example dataset by group factor
results_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=2,nrow=length(list_df))) # make an empty dataframe
colnames(results_df)<-c("intercept","Days") #give the dataframe column names

for (i in 1:length(list_df)){ #run a loop over the dataframes in the list
  mod<-lmer(Reaction~Days+(1|Subject),data=list_df[[i]]) #mixed model
  results_df[i,]<-fixef(mod) #extract coefficients to dataframe
  rownames(results_df)[i]<-names(list_df)[i] #assign rowname to results from data used
}
```